# Simplest way to show a dialog in AngularJS and return data from it

Tags: angularjs

I've setup an AngularJS grid using ng-grid which shows some tabular data (in the attached example it's a simplified version, as it needs collecting data from a REST service). This example includes a button which creates a new row:

```
<head lang="en">
<style = "text/css">
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px
}
</style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
    </head>

<script language="javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };

    $scope.addRow = function() {                         
        $scope.myData.push({name: 'Empty', age: 0});                             
    };

});
</script>


<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>

          <button ng-click="addRow()">New</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I'd like to replace the addRow function with a new one which opens a modal dialog where you enter data which is then inserted in the $scope.myData. I've found some options on the web for doing it like Ui Bootstrap, however all the examples I found include adding new dependencies, one more controller for managing the dialog and additionally some mechanism to share data between the two controllers. Being a newbie with AngularJS it's a bit overkill so I wonder if this can be achieved in a simpler way. Any idea ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a separate div which is hidden by default and add your model (data) in. The data could be filled by a `ng-click` event or even jquery `$('button').click(function(event){})` (although that is not really the angular way, you should use a directive for that but jquery works). So whenever a user clicks the button for adding a row, you show the div with your form and submit it to your controller (or directive) where you handle the data and add it to your scope.

So to summarize: button click shows hidden div with form which posts data to your controller which you process to save and show. Can do that with directives or just plain $('divname') jquery. If you are going to use jquery be sure to use `$scope.$apply(function(){})` if needed or else you won't see your changes.

Since i'm working on a Angular project myself with collegues who aren't very familiar with Angular, it seems that using jquery in my controllers is a way for them to understand whats happening even thats not really the angular-way. Then again, this seems way faster to code and understand if you are a beginner. Just know you still have stuff to learn. I've had the same experience and for every project i do i take a few small steps forward and doing more and more the angular-way

Comment: Thanks I have followed your advice.

Comment: And for who's interested, I contributed at writing this tutorial http://www.masterthescript.com/angularjs/angularjs-communication/building-a-full-restful-application-using-angularjs-and-wildfly-as which shows the interaction between AngularJS and a Java application server using REST services